# How do I make a list with a descriptive prefix?

Tags: horizontal-alignment, lists, itemize, boxes

This is an example of what I hope to achieve: a label is aligned to the left of the listed items.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

As we can guess, this environment is called `description`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\begin{document}

\begin{description}[style=multiline,leftmargin=8mm]
\item[DA]
\begin{itemize}
\item
This is an example of what I hope to achieve: a label is aligned to the left of the listed items.
\item
Enter image description here
\end{itemize}
\item[DA]
\begin{itemize}
\item
This is an example of what I hope to achieve: a label is aligned to the left of the listed items.
\item
Enter image description here
\end{itemize}
\end{description}



\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: This example is not quite compilable as it is.

Comment: @Gaussler Corrected. Thank you.

Comment: @PrzemysławScherwentke Thank you! However, in your solution the labels aren't vertically aligned.

Comment: @GingerBadger If you can use `enumitem` package, adding `\begin{description}[style=multiline,leftmargin=8mm]` (the exact value to be chosen) solves the problem.

Comment: @GingerBadger The answer is changed as in the above comment.